# Post Form Action to variable inside form

Tags: php, forms

I have the following form. I want to change the form action to include the variables inside this form, 500pxuserid. Is there a way to do this? For the user experience, I want to prevent a re-direct. Currently, I get the variable on the other side, and then re-route them a new url, but this required a re-direct.

```
      <form action="importphotos.php?view=500&mode=upload&page=1&u=&u2=&500pxuserid=" method="post">

    <div style="width:100%;height:45px;background-color:rgb(2,173,234);">
    <img style="width:30px;padding:10px;float:left;" src="https://photorankr.com/graphics/import_500pxicon.png" />
    <h3 style="font-weight:300;font-size:20px;text-align:left;padding-left:40px;margin-top:8px;color:white;float:left;">Login to 500px</h3>

    </div>

      <div style="width:90%;height:150px;border-bottom:1px solid rgba(255,255,255);float:left;margin-top:-5px;">


    <input style="outline:none;padding:8px;border-radius:3px;font-size:18px;width:263px;float:left;border:1px rgb(100,100,100);border-style:solid; margin:8px; margin-left:16px;" placeholder = "Enter your 500px id" type="text" name="500pxuserid" />
    <input type="password" style="outline:none;padding:8px;border-radius:3px;font-size:18px;width:263px;float:left;border:1px rgb(100,100,100);border-style:solid; margin:8px; margin-left:16px;"  placeholder = "Enter your 500px password" type="text" name="500pxuserpassword" />

    <input class = "submitbox" type="submit">

    </div>




    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Why not simply use `method="get"`?

Comment: You could change from `post` to `get`, or you could use javascript to add/change the url either on keyup or form submit

Comment: @Sean What would the javascript look like?

Comment: @Otome How would get work? I still have to get the variable on the other side. This would still require a redirect, correct?

Comment: Off-top: You should separate CSS from HTML...

Comment: If you want to retrieve the variable in the PHP code without the user having to submit a request, look into using AJAX.

Comment: @Otome I still want the user to submit a request, I just don't want a redirect on the other side. Is this possible or not?

Comment: you can use get method instead post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using javascript you could change the form action on form submit (onsubmit).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function get_action(form) {
    var user = document.getElementById('userid').value;
    form.action = "importphotos.php?view=500&mode=upload&page=1&u=&u2=&500pxuserid=" + user;
}
</script>

<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="get_action(this);">
  ...
   // add id=""userid" to input
  <input ... type="text" name="500pxuserid" id="userid" />
</form>
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work. It redirects to importphotos.php?view=500 What else should I change?

Comment: I edited my answer. I originally did `action="importphotos.php?view=500..."`, with the `...` a truncation, rather than the copy/pasting the full url. I have changed it though, so try what is now posted.

Comment: realized that `form.500pxuserid.value` is invalid, as `.500pxuserid.` was causing a syntax error. If you add an `id` to your `name="500pxuserid" input, you can then use `getElementById()`. See this jsfiddle example - http://jsfiddle.net/24Y7E/

Comment: this appears promising. However, when I add this code to my website and echo it out, it returns just the alert box from the jsfiddle  you linked. How can I get a proper redirect when echoing all this out, as I'm working in php?

Comment: Don't copy/paste the javascript in the jsFiddle example, as I used `alert()` to show the value, instead of posting a form. Use the javascript code in my answer above. It does not have the `alert()`, and will just change the form action, and allow it to submit/post.

Answer (score 0):

Three things:

- Add an [`id` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#adef-id) to your form. For example, `foo`.
- Add an [`onsubmit` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html) to your form, `onsubmit="foo()`"
- Add an [`id` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#adef-id) to your `500pxuserid` input. For example, `bar`.

It should look like this:

```
<form id="foo" onsubmit="foo();" ...
```

And your input:

```
<input id="bar" ...
```

And in your JavaScript add the following function:

```
function foo()
{
    var form = document.getElementById('foo'),
        bar = document.getElementById('bar');
    form.action = 'importphotos.php?view=500&mode=upload&page=1&u=&u2=&500pxuserid=' + bar.value; 
}
```

Also, keep in mind that this would only work if the user's browser has JavaScript enabled.